# R: How to replace . in a string?

Tags: regex, r

I have a string say "a.b" and I want to replace "." with "_".

```
gsub(".","_","a.b")
```

doesn't work as . matches all characters.

```
gsub("\.","_","a.b")
```

Just gives me an error.

Reading the documentation on ?gsub is not that helpful!

So how to do this straight-forward thing?

Comment: Try using gsub("\\.","_","a.b")

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`.` matches any character. Escape `.` using `\` to match `.` literally.

`\` itself is also should be escaped:

```
> gsub("\\.", "_", "a.b")
[1] "a_b"
```

Comment: @downvoter, Any reason for the downvote? Please, let me know how to improve the answer.

Answer (score 12):

You need to double escape `\\`, escaping `.` to match the literal dot and escaping `\` also. Keep in mind using `sub` replaces the first occurrence of a pattern, `gsub` replaces all occurrences.

```
string <- "a.b"
sub('\\.', '_', string)
[1] "a_b"

string <- "a.b.c.d.e.f"
gsub('\\.', '_', string)
[1] "a_b_c_d_e_f"
```

You can also use `sub` or `gsub` with the `fixed = TRUE` parameter. This takes the string representing the pattern you are searching for as it is ignoring special characters.

```
string <- "a.b"
sub('.', '_', string, fixed = TRUE)
[1] "a_b"
```

Answer (score 5):

try like this :

```
gsub("[.]","_","a.b")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [[:punct:]] regex syntax, as "." in itself is a punctuation character present in the string.

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]","_","a.b")
```

Output : `[1] "a_b"`

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use `stringr` (part of `tidyverse` packages)

`str_replace_all("ghyg.lo.poi","[.]","_")`