# Replace dashes with colon in part of string

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I have a dataframe with date and time values as characters, as extracted from a database.  Currently the date/time looks like this: `2017-03-17 11-56-20`

I want it to loook like this `2017-03-17 11:56:20`

It doesn't seem to be as simple as replacing all the dashes using gsub as in [R: How to replace . in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309876/r-how-to-replace-in-a-string)

I'm thinking it has something to do with the positioning, like telling R to only look after the space.  Ideas?

Comment: `as.character(strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", tz = ""))`?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 That looks like an answer to me :-)

Comment: `gsub("(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)$", "\\1:\\2:\\3", x)` is another option, which would not use R's date/time API, possibly not a good solution

Comment: That was so easy!  Works perfectly and simply.  You rock.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If the goal is to just get a character string thoug, I'm pretty sure `gsub` would be faster than `strptime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're dealing with a date-time object, you can use `strptime`:

```
x <- "2017-03-17 11-56-20"
as.character(strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", tz = ""))
# [1] "2017-03-17 11:56:20"
```

Comment: And as.POSIXct works too- even better for the long run.  
I was going for simple, baby steps first.

Answer (score 3):

Try matching the following pattern:

```
(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)$
```

and then replace that with:

```
\\1:\\2:\\3
```

This will match your timestamp exclusively, because of the terminal anchor `$` at the end of the pattern.  Then, we rebuild the timestamp the way you want using colons and the three capture groups.

```
gsub("(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)$", "\\1:\\2:\\3", x)
[1] "2017-03-17 11:56:20"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `library(anytime)` to take care of the formatting for you too (which also coerces to `POSIX`)

```
library(anytime)

anytime(x)
# [1] "2017-03-17 11:56:20 AEDT"

as.character(anytime(x))
# [1] "2017-03-17 11:56:20"
```